# regex account for single letters or multiple based on list

Tags: regex, python-2.7

My goal is to find all matches in a word list using regex. I got it working, but I would like to be able to specify multiple letters and have each letter occur only the number of times it is specified.

my code:

```
import re
with open('wordlist.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

def search(regex):
    pattern=re.compile(regex)
    for word in content:
        word=word.strip()
        if(pattern.findall(word)):
            print(word)
```

Examples:

```
search(r'^(b|e|a|c|h|e|s|q|r){7}$') match only words with 7 of those 9 letters. only letters in the word can be those 9. In this case beaches would be returned
search(r'^(f|o|o|c|l|t){4}$') match only words with 4 of those 6 letters. only letters in the word can be those 6. In this case foot and fool and colt would be returned
search(r'^(f|o|d|c|l|t){4}$') match only words with 4 of those 6 letters. only letters in the word can be those 6. In this case only colt would be returned
```

Comment: What you do now is the same as `^([foclt]{4})$`. This seems to be very tricky with regex. I think you could just have an array of size 26 where you specify how many times a letter may occur and then parse the word counting the letters and as soon as it exceeds the limit you can skip the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that a regex is the way to go here. You don't care about order, just about how many of each letter there are. That sounds like a job for an array or a `dict`.

How about making the argument to `search` a `dict` where the keys are each letter, and the values are the number of times that letter is allowed to appear? Then just deep copy the `dict`, iterate over the string, and decrement. If the key's not found, or it's already 0, fail and move on to the next string.